# Laravel migrations: create referenced table before making a reference to it

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreign-keys, relationship

Here is my migration method:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('item_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('character_class');
        $table->integer('character_race');
        $table->integer('required_level');
        $table->integer('quality');
        $table->integer('durability');
        $table->integer('buy_price');
        $table->integer('sell_price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('items', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('item_type_id')->references('id')->on('item_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The problem is that migration for the `item_types` table is after `items` migration. So there is no `item_types` table while creating `items` table, then migration will fail at creating foreign key.
Is there a way to delay foreign constraints and run them after table creations?
Or I have to separate the foreign constraints to another migration?!
Thanks.

Comment: First create the `item_types` table and after creating it you can create the `items` table with the foreign key.. As a side note.. I don't recommend using cascade deletion.. it is very dangerous..

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

#### 1

Create `item_types` table before this migration (which is natural situation).

#### 2

If the above is imposible for some reason then you have to move this:

```
Schema::table('items', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('item_type_id')->references('id')->on('item_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

To the end of `up` method in `item_types` table migration.